# How to print selected div instead complete page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have two divs: `div1` and `div2`.

Maintaining the original css styles applied to the `div2` element being printed.

I don't want to print content inside `div1` but only the inside of `div2`.

How to print?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print
{
body * { visibility: hidden; }
.div2 * { visibility: visible; }
.div2 { position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 30px; }
}
</style>
```

Comment: You have to handle it for ipad for Ex: @media only screen and (max-width:768px){...your style here.....} etc.

Answer (score 19):

Using my following solution you can print the specific div content from your web page if you don't want to print your full page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 



<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data)
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'new div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="yourdiv">
    Div you want to print. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a quam at nibh adipiscing interdum. Nulla vitae accumsan ante. 
</div>

<div>
    This will not be printed.
</div>

<div id="anotherdiv">
    Nor will this.
</div>

<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="PrintElem('#yourdiv')" />

</body>
</html>
```

[Live Demo](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2013/07/print-contents-of-specific-div-using.html)

Comment: the demo is broken

Answer (score 3):

You can only print a whole page, not part ofg a page. So, there is two options, you can either copy the content of one element into a new page and print that, or prevent the other element from being printed.

You can use a media css to hide one element from printing. Example:

```
@media print {

   .div1 { display: none; }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv() {    
    var printContents = document.getElementById('Your printable div').innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @ChrisHappy I believe it's probably due to the event listeners being removed/lost when the document.body.innerHTML gets replaced

Comment: @DanTheMan yeah, you are right but how can we resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the jqPrint plugin for jQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using jQuery:

```
<script>
function printArea(){
    $('body').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.div2').css('visibility', 'visible');
    window.print();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would doubt you can hide the body and then show something inside it

Answer (score 1):

I faced lots of issues while printing a div (part of HTML) using window.print(). Used below method and it works seamlessly in edge, chrome and Mozilla. How this below function helps mitigate the issue that I face is by the use of iframe. When using window.print() without the below code it was printing most of the page's design and all, which we didn't want. There are many CSS based options too but eventually this one below worked for me. From the below code "frameDoc.document.write........ frameDoc.document.close();" is controlling the format that can be seen in print preview as well.

```
function printDiv(id) {
      var contents = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
        var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
        frame1.name = "frame1";
        frame1.style.position = "absolute";
        frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
        document.body.appendChild(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        frameDoc.document.write("<html><head>\n\n                " +
            "<style type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\">\n                       " +
            "@@page\n                    {\n                        " +
            "size:  auto;   /* auto is the initial value */\n                        " +
            "margin: 10mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */\n    " +
            "                }\n\n                    html\n                    {\n    " +
            "                    background-color: #FFFFFF;\n         " +
            "           }\n\n                    body\n                " +
            "    {   font-family:\"Times New Roman\", Times, serif;\n             " +
            "           border: none ;\n                  " +
            "      margin: 0; /* margin you want for the content */\n                " +
            "    }\n                   .table {\n                    width: 100%;\n      " +
            "              max-width: 100%;\n                    margin-bottom: 20px;\n        " +
            "            border-collapse: collapse;\n                 " +
            "   background-color: transparent;\n                    display: table;\n        " +
            "        }\n                .table-bordered {\n                 " +
            "   border: 1px solid #ccc;\n                }\n                tr {\n            " +
            "        display: table-row;\n                    vertical-align: inherit;\n              " +
            "      border-color: inherit;\n                    padding:15px;\n                }\n      " +
            "          .table-bordered tr td {border: 1px solid #ccc!important; padding:15px!important;}\n   " +
            "             </style><title></title></head><body>".concat(contents, "</body>"));
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            document.body.removeChild(frame1);
        }, 500);
        return false;
}
```

Call this like

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:printDiv('divwithcontenttoprint')"> Print </a>
```

Comment: Glad to see you posting answers! Do keep in mind that you are expected to add some details about what you fixed or why it is right. It helps users understand what is going on, rather than just being served the answer. Consider it a rule for all your answers here. I hope you have a good time.

Comment: thanks for the suggeston. Added more into to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way

```
@media print {
    body > div { display:none; }
    body .div { display:block; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.class-toggle { display: inline-block; }
#div1, #div2 { display: none; }
```

```js
function classToggle() {
  $('#div1').addClass('class-toggle');
}

classToggle();
```

Then you can play with event handler to handle how and when you want to 
   print the output.

Answer (score -1):

Use PrintArea jQuery Plugin to print specific div content. I have found the easy integration guide from here - [How to print a specific area of the web page using jQuery](http://www.codexworld.com/print-specific-area-of-web-page-using-jquery/)

You need only the following code to use PrintArea jQuery Plugin.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#printButton").click(function(){
        var mode = 'iframe';
        var close = mode == "popup";
        var options = { mode : mode, popClose : close};
        $("div.printableArea").printArea( options );
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv() {    
    var printContents = document.getElementById('Your printable div').innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script>
```