# Printing different part of page depending on clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm looking for a clever way to print a small part of a page, depending on what link the user is clicking. An example:

```
Item 1  PRINT
Item 2  PRINT
```

If I click on print next to Item 1, I just want Item 1 to open up in print dialog. Likewise I only want Item 2 to open up if I click next to that item.

I know of `<a href="javascript:window.print()">` and how to add for instance a class named `noprint` to whatever element I would like not to be printed, but what I'm looking for is some clever, dynamic way of having it change depending on what element on the page the user is interacting with.

Anyone know of a way to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373922/jquery-print-selected-div-instead-complete-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my favorite way of doing it. It doesn't work here on S/O, but it works in [this pen](http://codepen.io/tmorrow-hyphensolutions/pen/JYqRjd)

```js
    function printDiv(id) {    
      var printContents = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
      var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
      document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
      window.print();
      document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
```

```html
<div id="first">I'm first</div>
<button onclick="printDiv('first')">Print</button>
<div id="second">I'm second</div>
<button onclick="printDiv('second')">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create separate action on backend which will render desired item in appropriate ready to print view (somthing like `/print?itemId=123`)
2. By click on link open that view in separate window and there call `window.print();`

It seems like a big job for small task, but you'll get significant benefit of independent and flexible on-screen and print views of same item.