# Is there any approach to print particular div using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to print particular div using Ajax/Jquery, As of now I am using below Javascript function, But it screws up all the dynamic functionality of the page: buttons etc,

### JSP:

```
    <div id="printableArea">content</div>
<input class="printButton" type="button" value="Print" name="print"
            onclick="printDiv()">

<script>
    function printDiv() {
        var printContents = document.getElementById("printableArea").innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script>
```

Please let me know how to solve this, I am not able to find any proper JQuery code(working).

Comment: Your code is working fine. what do you mean by screws up all the dynamic   functionality.

Comment: I m using jquery plugin to highlight the tab when selected, When I use print functionality, and then try to navigate to other tab then the Jquery function to highlight tab is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are replacing your body content, with the content of the div you want to print.

This of course generates a number of problems and may be hard to fix, one of them being the one pointed out by @Alexander Capone.

So, instead of doing that, you can:

1. Open a pop-up, fill it with the desired content, print (personally I prefer this one although is less popular).
2. Use @media print.

You can find exactly how to do each here: [How to print selected div instead complete page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373922/jquery-print-selected-div-instead-complete-page) (first 2 answers).

Comment: I changed the code to jquery, <script type="text/javascript" src="/eidsar/js/jQuery.print.js"></script>                                                     function printDiv() {
  $("#showLogo").css({ 'display': "block" });
  $("#printableArea").print();
  $("#showLogo").css({ 'display': "none" });
  return true; 
 }   But for the second time when I print, I its not working. Why is that?

Comment: When you say is not working... what do you mean? Any error in console? If you add an alert or something in the function, is it executed?

Comment: $("#printableArea").print(); this is not getting executed

Comment: If you console.log($("#printableArea")); what do you get?

Comment: Not able to get anything. Its blank

Comment: You mean an empty object right? If yes, my guess is that your div was removed from the dom (or your selector is wrong). Since it is not found there is no event to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I can assume that 'Screws up dynamic functionality' means that some custom jquery events, such as mouseover, click events stopped working after you re-inserted the HTML. If this is the case, problem is hiding in the way you attached those events to HTML elements.
Instead of attaching event like this:

```
$('.some-class').click(function(){ 
    //do logic;
})
```

You should attach event on a document element, so page knows how to delegate event to any html element in any point of discrete time.

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-class', function () {
    //do logic;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but it seems like you are overwriting  your body contents with these lines in the code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```