# How to create insert and print using one submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How can I create a submit button that allow multiple action? In this case I would like the button to add new data and print the new data using one single submit button.

However, after added `onclick="printContent('div1')"` on my submit button, the INSERT query does not work. Thus, it will print old latest info because no new data was added.

index.php:

```
<html>
        <?php
            // Turn off all error reporting
            error_reporting(0);

            include 'dbconnect.php';
         ?>
    <head>
     <script>
                // script to print partial information only
                function printContent(el){
                var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
                var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
                document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
                window.print();
                document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
          <button name="submit" type="submit" id="printStuff" class="btn v-btn no-three-d" onclick="printContent('div1')">PRINT!</button>
    </form>

      <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
               $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Q_postitem (service_ID, created_time, queue_No) 
               SELECT 1, CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'+00:00','+8:00'), max(queue_No)+1 FROM Q_postitem WHERE service_ID=1";

               if (mysqli_query($con, $sql2)) {
                  echo "New record created successfully";
                  } else {
                  echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "" . mysqli_error($con);
                  }

                  echo "<br>".$sql2;

             mysqli_close($con);
             } 

      ?>

     <div id="div1" style="display: none;">
      //ECHO NEW ADDED DATA HERE TO PRINT
     </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you can write a click event and then so an ajax and insert the data and on the success message you can print the same data..

Comment: Also destroying and rebuilding the DOM just to print is silly. Use a print CSS that only prints what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373922/how-to-print-selected-div-instead-complete-page

Comment: @mplungjan in real codes there are 4 submit button so i think CSS solution wont solve this issue. I tried the CSS solution already..

Comment: Of course it will. You can even insert the CSS dynamically or use any of the popup versions in the link I gave

Comment: I think i got your idea. Let me try!

Comment: the pop out version is not working @mplungjan

Comment: What does that mean? Console errors?

Comment: i click 'print' button, nothing is happening. @mplungjan

Comment: Any errors in the console?